# calling a oracle stored proc from shell passing schema name and dblink as parameter

Tags: oracle, shell, stored-procedures

I have a shell file which sets the variable. it looks like this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure MIG.dblink(schema1 in varchar, link1 in varchar, count1 out number)
IS

BEGIN

SELECT COUNT(1) INTO COUNT1 FROM schema1.table@link1 where trunc(csactivated) > trunc(sysdate-1);

END;
/
```

now i am calling this from a shell file which looks like below.

```
source dataenv.sh #sets up the following variables.

    echo "SCHEMA_NAME IS $SCHEMA_NAME"
    echo "LINKNAME IS $LINKNAME"
    echo "ORACLEHOME IS $ORACLEHOME"
    echo "DBUSER IS $DBUSER"
    echo "DBPASSWORD IS $DBPASSWORD"
    echo "HOSTNAME IS $HOST_NAME"

    output1=0

    output=$(
      $ORACLEHOME/bin/sqlplus -s $DBUSER/$DBPASSWORD <<EOF
       exec dblink('$SCHEMA_NAME', '$LINKNAME', $output1);
    EOF
    )

    echo "output is $output"
```

now my issue is i cant compile the procedure as oracle can't find schema1 schema and link1 dblink. any suggestion please?

Comment: Why do you want to use a procedure for this?

Comment: exactly! poor me...can be done using a normal sql query... :)...thanks mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a procedure - in fact it would make life harder than you think as you would have to use dynamic SQL. Just use plain SQL  uilt from your shell variables:

```
output=$(
  $ORACLEHOME/bin/sqlplus -s $DBUSER/$DBPASSWORD <<EOF
   set pages 0 feedback off
   select count(*) from ${SCHEMA_NAME}.table@${LINKNAME}
   where trunc(csactivated) > trunc(sysdate-1);
EOF
)
```

I've added a couple of `set` commands to trim noise from the output.

Also not sure you need or want to trunc the table column (affects index use, for a start), so avoid that and adjust the right-hand side to get the data you want.